# Convert XML to CSV: Data is stored as attribute

Tags: xml, csv

```
<cids>
<defect name="29237" action="decided" checker="OVERRUN_STATIC" cid="29237"/>
<defect ....

</cids>
```

I want to convert this xml to CSV I checked many links but didn't find any link where XML is converted to CSV by parsing attributes.

Comment: It might be overkill for simple xml files but you could deserialize your xml file first to java classes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454240/generate-java-class-from-xml-file-using-xstream) and then just write all fields to a csv file.

Comment: or using xslt you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Windows command line

```
for /F tokens^=2^,4^,6^,8^ delims^=^" %a in ('type data.xml ^| find "<defect" ') do echo %a,%b,%c,%d >> data.csv
```

AWK (in this case, also from windows command line)

```
awk -F \" -v OFS=, "/^<defec/{print $2,$4,$6,$8}" data.xml > data.csv
```

In both cases, using quotes as delimiter to split records into fields.

Answer (score 1):

As no language or anything was asked, this is a vim command (tested on vim 7.3 for windows)

```
%s/<defect \w\+="\(.\+\)" \w\+="\(.\+\)" \w\+="\(.\+\)" \w\+="\(.\+\)"\/>/\1,\2,\3,\4/g
```

THEN, delete the first and last line by hand.