# Is it possible to create class diagram from XML?

Tags: xml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I want to know if it's possible to create a class diagram from an XML file?
I have a code generator created by my self which reads the properties from an XML file and creates my classes. Is it possible to create a class diagram too?
I think there may be a way in soft wares like Visual Paradigm to import an XML file with a specific format to create a class diagram from.
Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the XML and output the details in a string format defined by [YUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/samples) for class diagrams.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a more common software like: visual paradigm, rational rose,visio,etc...

Comment: I'm suggest you generate a java source file from XML and then let the tools like visual paradigm generate the class diagram from the source then.

Comment: Would you please let me now how to do this?

Comment: See something like [generate-java-class-from-xml-file-using-xstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454240/generate-java-class-from-xml-file-using-xstream)